# Asterisk: Create an outbound call and bridge it with a current active inbound channel

Tags: asterisk, agent, bridge, outbound, inbound

I am using Asterisk to make a CAll-Center. The whole process is:

1. Calls from outside to the Call-Center: all calls put in queue and each one connect to an available agent.
2. From the Agent, he/she puts the inbound call on hold and create an outbound call
3. Then, bridge the inbound and outbound channels together; At that moment, the caller (inbound channel), the agent, and the callee (outbound channel) can communicate to each other.
4. Then, the Agent gets out from the conference and let the caller and callee start a communication.
   Please help me out!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do called "attended transfer".

Please consult your callcenter documentation about how to do attended transfer(usually *2,enter number, if ok just hangup call with B party to connect A&B).

Comment: Attended transfer does not have an option which the Agent talks to both parties at the same time.

Comment: if you need talk to both, use conference/transfer to conference. You can also do it via features.conf macros.

Comment: Could you explain more details please? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I already described you full plan. To understand details, you need have enought knowledge.Please read any book like "Asterisk the Future of Telephony".

Comment: Thank you very much Arheops, I used Conference and ChanRedirect. It works very well. Thank you very much for your help!